# Celery cancels itself

Tags: python, redis, celery, broker

When I try to run a worker:

`celery -A celery_conf --loglevel=debug worker -Q celery -c 1`

It seems to start, but then it "cancel"s

```
[2018-08-07 16:25:16,132: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://server:6379/1
[2018-08-07 16:25:23,984: DEBUG/MainProcess] Canceling task consumer...
[2018-08-07 16:25:24,993: DEBUG/MainProcess] Canceling task consumer...
[2018-08-07 16:25:24,993: DEBUG/MainProcess] Closing consumer channel...
[2018-08-07 16:25:24,993: WARNING/MainProcess] Restoring 1 unacknowledged message(s)
[2018-08-07 16:25:24,996: DEBUG/MainProcess] removing tasks from inqueue until task handler finished
```

Any idea how to begin debugging? I already have the loglevel to DEBUG.

- Celery version: 4.2.1 (also tested on master)
- Python version: 3.6.6
- Using a Redis Broker

Comment: Can you share more info? celery version? worker code? are u using redis as backend? broker?

Comment: I updated to add more info, worker invocation is already present

Comment: Can you share your code? Maybe there is something in the code that makes this happen

Comment: I'd love to, but there is too much. I'm looking for advice on how to debug this. So far what i've ended up doing is going into the celery source and printing debug statements.

Comment: This was a temporary Celery bug that got fixed, can we please close this thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

downgrade your redis-py to `redis>=2.10.0,<3.0.0`, or just upgrade your celery version to 4.3.0(I didn't try this, I down)

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4495#issuecomment-440438055